# Unable to access Views fields in block Twig template

Tags: views, theming, blocks

How Drupal 8 uses Twig, how different data is transferred from general template to specific templates?

For view block I have created block template as per default template suggestions. In my new Twig template if I print `{{ content }}` everything (view result fields) are getting rendered as per Drupal default.

How can I access and apply my theme markup to all view fields in my block template. `{{ dump(_context|keys) }}` display below.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In **block--views-block--page-fields-block-1.html.twig**

You can access the view fields like this:

```
{% for row in content['#view'].result %}

  {{ content['#view'].field['field_name'].value(row) }} 
  // change field_name to the actual field machine name. 

{% endfor %}
```

---

Personally, I rather use **views-view-fields--[view-name]--[[machine-name]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDJ1q.jpg).html.twig**

In your case should be views-view-fields--page-fields--block-1.html.twig

Here you do not need to do a `for` loop and you can access the fields easily with:

```
{{ fields.field_name.content }}
// change field_name to the actual field machine name.
```

Comment: Now how can i get field_image url with first approach, currently getting file id

Comment: @harish use the [Image URL Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_url_formatter) module. Then in views click on your image field and set the formatter to URL.

Comment: That i have in D8 without any module, in dashboard view results i get image file url, but in view template your above twig syntax gives numeric value ( target file_id ) need to find how to get entity and then uri from this numeric file id

Comment: How can i get header and footer for view

Comment: @NoSssweat  thanks for ans  but i want URL value with same code above {{ content['#view'].field['field_name'].value(row) }}

Answer (score 1):

If you want to render the block into your custom template:

1. Create your twig file `block--views-block-page-fields-block-1.html.twig` inside `templates` folder in your custom module.
2. implement `hook_theme` like the following:

```
    /**
     * Implements hook_theme().
     */
    function yourModuleName_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
      return [
        'block__views_block_page_fields_block-1'     => [
          'base hook' => 'block'
        ],
      ];
    }
```

3. Clear cache.
4. Now you have `content` variable.

If you use [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) you can use `drupal_view_result` to get view result, so you can access to the fields like:

```
{% for result in drupal_view_result(content['#view'].id, content['#view'].current_display) %}
  {{ result._entity.field_name.value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer....I am having access to content variable without hook_theme, My question is how can i access specific fields in my template using content. e.g. field_title, field_field_slides from this content variables as i shared in image none of key in content taking me to view fields

Comment: I want something information that i can traverse through content variable to get my view fields .... don't i have access them in this block template ?

Comment: The question wasn't about rendering a block... was about how to access view field values.

Comment: Thanks ..Twig tweak approach is also working..Good that i could easily get image source for image field    result._entity.field_image.entity.fileuri

Comment: You are welcome, i'm glad that help.

Comment: bamboo twig is also good..